Как проверить количество загруженных изображений и на основании этого поставить условие?
Мне необходимо вывести на странице галерею изображений, загруженных в произвольные поля, созданные при помощи плагина "Carbon Fileds".
Поля созданы подобным образом, в отдельном файле:
Container::make( 'post_meta', 'Редактирование информации о подразделении' )
->where( 'post_template', '=', 'page-templates/departments-item.php' )
  ->add_fields( array(
    Field::make( 'textarea', 'depart_preview_text', 'Краткое описание (для главной страницы)' ),
    Field::make( 'image', 'depart_preview_img', 'Превью изображение' )
      -> set_value_type( 'url' ),
    Field::make( 'media_gallery', 'depart_gallery', 'Основные изображения для страницы подразделения' )
      -> set_type( 'image' ),
            ) );
}

Вывожу в php-шаблоне в слайдер так:
<div class="department">
    <div class="department__slider swiper department-swiper">
        <div class="department__slider-wrap swiper-wrapper">
            <?php $slides = carbon_get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'depart_gallery');
                foreach ($slides as $slide):
            ?>
                <div class="department__slider-item swiper-slide">
                    <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_url($slide, 'full'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title() ?>"/>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Вопрос в следующем, как сделать проверку на количество загруженных изображений и поставить условие: если загружено одно изображение, то отображаем простой html-блок с фото, если их несколько, то через foreach выводим все имеющиеся фотки в слайдер (как уже и сделано в коде выше).
Спасибо.

Наверное, через проверку <?php if count($slides) == 1?
